# Does anyone still use "skyrocket" in the original sense?

Tags: meaning, dialects

In US English, I can't recall having heard this word used to describe a reaction-drive pyrotechnic or vehicle in many years.
Almost invariably, the word as used describes a rapid or exponential increase in statistical measures.

Is this the case in other dialects of English or is it strictly a US or even regional phenomenon?

Are there any other common words that have a new, highly-specific usage that is so far removed from the original usage?

Comment: Usages like [Prices have skyrocketed in recent years](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+skyrocketed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) seem perfectly ordinary to me as a BrE speaker, but comparing BrE to AmE prevalence figures in [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+skyrocketed&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20skyrocketed%3B%2Cc0), it does seem to be about three times more common in the latter, so I guess you could say there's a regional difference.

Comment: ...for the more general case, I'd say it's a truism that *most* common words have new highly-specific usages that are far removed from the original meaning. Language is constantly changing, particularly when it comes to idioms and slang.

Comment: _Mouse_ is another one of those words... when used, it hardly ever refers to an actual rodent. :-)

Comment: From [Wikipedia s.v. *skyrocket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyrocket): "A common misconception about professional fireworks displays is that skyrockets are used to propel the pyrotechnic effects into the air. In reality, skyrockets are more widely used as a consumer item. Professional fireworks displays utilize mortars to fire aerial shells into the air, not rockets."

Comment: The is a rare case where we can at least roughly discriminate the literal from metaphorical usage by [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skyrocket_NOUN%2Cskyrocket_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3), since literal usage tends to be as a noun, metaphorical as a verb. Verb overtook noun about 1962.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Perhaps that transition is what caused this particular example to seem jarring to me, along with the specific new usage.  I think the new usage is only very common among journalists and pundits, but that is base speculation on my part.

Comment: I keep thinking of the 70s hit song "sky rockets in the night… Afternoon delight "

Comment: I hate that song so much I'm not even going to correct your interpretation of its lyrics.

Comment: @Robusto I also dislike that song, except as performed by a fictional news team.

Comment: @Robusto actually, all joking aside, you're right: it's not a literal use -- it's yet another figurative use, albeit a different one!

Comment: When land-rockets come into their own, *skyrocket* may come back into vogue, to distinguish the one from the other. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoKeab4NvAQ)

Comment: 'Launder' only ever refers to black money; my reading of the Ngram is that the domestic meaning went down the drain at the same time that 'skyrockets'  fizzled out.

Comment: One thing that might have contributed to the diminished usage of the literal noun is that most communities now severely limit the kind of fireworks that common people can buy (or ban them outright), so children do not grow up experiencing "skyrockets".  Only professional pyrotechnicians get to set off skyrockets, and IIUC they refer to these by their payload, as "shells". (they are bombs that happen to be skyrockets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in an earlier comment by Brian Donovan, Google Ngram Viewer can be helpful here. We can see that skyrocket in both senses shows up in the [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skyrocket_NOUN%2Cskyrocket_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskyrocket_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocket_VERB%3B%2Cc0) *and* the [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skyrocket_NOUN%2Cskyrocket_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskyrocket_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocket_VERB%3B%2Cc0) corpuses. In both cases, the noun use peaked in the 1940s. So, the noun use is less common and probably dated, but not extinct and the noun might be more common in American English, but appears in British English as well.

As oerkelens suggested, computing terms are a rich source of words where new meanings have overtaken old. Oerkelens used "mouse" as an example. "Computer" itself is also an example, since it now means a machine and not an individual who does computations. An example closer to "skyrocket" is "feedback". Originally it was a concrete technical or engineering term (like "skyrocket"), which survives in terms like "force feedback". However, the related business use ("can you give me feedback on this?") has overtaken the old technical meaning.

Comment: "However, the related business use ("can you give me feedback on this?") has overtaken the old technical meaning." I think it's basically the same meaning, just not as technical. You're still indirectly converting output into input to be fed back into some system.